# Should the design of this site incorporate some ideas from skeptics.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, site-design

Please have a look at [Stack Exchange's site for skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) , which is:

> A site for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results

Patents SE (our site) serves a similar mission, our [primary goal](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq) is to help others to discover prior art needed to invalidate bad patents. The design for Skeptics incorporates elements that suggest time being spent crunching data and other fact checking. Should our design help to suggest the work that goes into searching for prior art? If yes, how could it be changed?

I am extremely impressed and delighted with the design of our site, I just happened upon a question asked at Skeptics and noticed the design a bit more closely.

Comment: *"The design for Skeptics incorporates elements that suggest ..."* — Can you cite some example(s) that illustrates how the site design helps forward the goal of Skeptics... and maybe add an example of what type of ideas you are trying to solicit here? I'm not entirely clear where specifically you feel the current design can be improved, but making the **primary** purpose of this site **more obvious** is certainly a challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the Skeptics site design the worst of all the sites - the glaring yellow and black make it very hard for me to read. Until I went over to look, I didn't even realise there was detail in the background as it just doesn't show on my usual screens.

I far prefer the patents site design - guessing the diagrams are from historical patents.

Comment: I didn't mean the colors. The background graphics suggest what the site is about (graphs, data, etc). I love our current design too, and I don't want it to look like skeptics, I just liked how well the design itself suggests the main focus of the site is all.